# Xcode Create .xib File For Already Created Files

Tags: xcode, file, xib, implementation

I have a few files (.h and .m) that do not have a corresponding .xib or storyboard file connected to them. I know how to create a new .xib file but how would I create one and have it connect to the other files that correspond to it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Simply creating it and including it in the target will suffice. 
The default implementation of `loadView` will look for a NIB/XIB with the same name as the class (take a look at the `UIViewController` documentation for more information on that process.)

If your class has bindings, just name them correctly and add `IBOutlet` before them in the header file to make them visible in IB.

If you have overridden your initializer, you may need to incorporate some calls to `super`. The easiest way to see exactly what would be to create another view controller and add a XIB at the same time using Xcode's interface, and take a look at what is created. This isn't likely, though, as most calls to `super` end up going through the right path in the long run.

Post specifics if you have difficulty.

Comment: Okay so I created the .xib file and named it the same as my .h and .m files but after opening the files owner I noticed that none of my IBOutlets are there, meaning it is still not hooked up correctly...

Comment: Max, below, has got the additional step - make sure you set the class for the xib! Sorry to leave that out.

Answer (score 2):

First add new file as user interface and select view. Then give name whatever you want. then in that xib file's "File's Owner" set the class for what you want xib file.

[image: see this image for setting class]

then bind the view with "File's owner"'s view. That shit.. Now you can access that class by `initWithNibName` method and in that method give nib name of that newly created xib file. may be it works for you.